# Inheriting from auto-generated classes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a project with MVC 4 and Entity Framework.

I have created the entity model with autogenerated classes from database. But, I want different names and methods for classes in the Models.

For instance, it has been generated this class:

```
 public partial class tbl_Templates
    {
        public tbl_Templates()
        {
            this.tbl_Template_Sections = new HashSet<tbl_Template_Sections>();
        }

         public int TemplateId { get; set; }

         //...
    }
```

But i dont want to use this class, so I have created my own class in the modeler:

```
public class Template : tbl_Templates
{
    public Template()
        : base()
    {

    }

    // I'll add custom methods later
}
```

Now, how can I use this one in the controller?

I tried:

```
  List<Template> Templates =db.tbl_Templates.Cast<Template>().ToList();
```

but i get the exception:

> LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Why don't you just rename the classes in the model?

Comment: Because I also want to create separated layers: Data Access (the tbl_* autogenerated classes) and the Business Logic

Comment: If you did `ToList().Cast<Template>()` does this work?

Comment: Nope, I get `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.tbl_Templates_BDCB2400F8F15817C025FC5304B7B50595C8747A92C936DFB2D4412FA01BB315' to type 'Project1.Models.Template'.`.

Comment: If you use inheritance you are still exposing the underlying object to the clients. If you don't want to do that, you have to create some other models (view models perhaps?) and map the properties across. Automapper would do that nicely.

Comment: @DavidG Can you be more precise or provide some example, please? A full answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework Designer?

Comment: why don't you just change the name of the entity in the designer? eg right click on the table in the designer (tbl_Template) --> Select Properties -->  Change the Name to "Template." This will will not effect the underlying datatable name... Also, by exposing "db" in your controllers you really aren't creating a BLL-DAL layered architecture in your application..

Comment: How to create a BLL-DAL layered architecture in my application?

Comment: I agree with @wahwahwah. Keep it simple and rename the classes in the designer. Even better, rename the tables in the database if you can. If you need extra methods, you can create a partial class definition of the same class generated by the designer without using inheritance.

Comment: While the answer you accepted is perfectly accurate / relevant based on your question, obfuscating your entity names so they do not resemble your table names does nothing to promote separation of concerns. Your DAL should be the only layer that knows about your "Context."  The BLL should provide some form of data access service and your controllers should consume these services. Just change the names in your designer and save yourself the hassle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `Select` a `Template` and map all the properties across.  Something like this

```
List<Template> Templates = db.tbl_Templates.Select(x => new Template { 
                                                            .TemplateID = x.TemplateID 
                                                   }).ToList();
```

If both types have the same property names, you can do this automatically with [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).  They  have [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) on how to use the queryable extensions.  Here's a sample

```
Mapper.CreateMap<tbl_Templates, Template>();

List<Templates> Templates = db.tbl_Templates.Project().To<Template>().ToList();
```